# Asp.net guess controller name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I´m using asp.net core, and my controller name is "ConsultasController".

When pointing to `localhost:5000\consultas` an error says that there is no route for this.

So if I change to `localhost:5000\consultum` it works.

Why this is happening ?

Comment: We need to know how your routes are configured and what `RouteAttribute`s you've used.

Comment: Time for you to start reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I have made no configurations other than default.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things to consider checking as without a breakdown of your routes and what your controller declarations look like, we would simply be guessing as to what could be the issue.

**Check Your Default Routing**

As long as you are using the default routes within your application, ASP.NET MVC should still use the name of your Controller to determine the route :

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller}/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Do you have any other custom routes defined? Or is your default route pointing to the wrong location (i.e. `Consultum` instead of `Consultas`)?

**Ensure Your Naming Is Correct**

If you changed the name of your Controller, you'll want to ensure that you changed both the name of the class `ConsultasController` and the name of the file (`ConsultasController.cs`) and not just one or the other.

**Any `Route` Attributes?**

Additionally, do you have any specific route attributes defined for this Controller that could override the existing default routing? You'll want to ensure that your `ConstultasController` isn't pointing to `ConsultumController` :

```
[Route("Consultum")]
public class ConsultasController : Controller 
{
      /* Your code here */
}
```